# Can't enter password after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: upgrade, login, password, login-screen

After upgrading to 18.04 the login prompt on my laptop acts really strange:

It wait's for the input of the user name and after pressing `ENTER` it behaves as if the `ENTER` key is stuck and gives no chance to enter the password.

Here is a picture:

[image: defect login prompt]

The exact step that happen are as following:

**1.** It shows the normal login prompt

> Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS computername tty1
>
> computername login: _

**2.** It wait's for the input of the username and until you entered the username it behaves normally.

**3.** As soon as you press `ENTER` to confirm the username it immediately goes on to

> Password:
>
> Password:
>
> Login incorrect.

Without waiting for any user input.

So there is no chance to login to this PC anymore?!

Comment: Did you update any GPU drivers? such AMD or Nvidia? If so, you have to install the nvidia/AMD xorg server for each of these.

Comment: @Ronald To be honest I don't know what was updated - a few thousand packages as usual in a relase upgrade ... but how should I be able to install these packages, if I can't even login on the shell? (The problem is similar on the GUI btw, it acts normally but won't let you log in.)

Comment: This is a known bug introduced with kernel `4.15.0-44-generic`. Try to go back to kernel *-43, at least temporarily until a fix is published. Bugreport on launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1812095

Comment: @s1lv3r as PerlDuck said, looks like it's a bug. It happened this me once in Ubuntu and somehow the nvidia drivers installed normally, but not the xorg nvidia driver, so i have to log in into that console and install it from the repositories: 
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

Comment: Ah okay ... but how am I supposed to revert the kernel version, without beeing able to login? Do I have to boot from a live CD?

Comment: Doesn't your GRUB menu show up before the login prompt appears? From there you can select other kernels (if they are installed).

Comment: Thank you very much Ronald and PerlDuck for the fast support. :-) The login issue on the TTY was really this kernel bug. It works with the older versions. Not beeing able to login via GUI seems to be a totally separate issue, the dist upgrade seems to be botched somehow - still working on that one, but atleast I have a shell to work with now.